# GetConnectionString using IHostBuilder

Tags: azure, configuration, app-config, azure-webapps

(using .NET 6.0)

I used these commands to set a connection string:

- dotnet user-secrets init
- dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:AppConfig "{myconnectionstring}"

but I can't figure out how to retrieve that connection string using IHostBuilder. This returns a null string:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configurationBuilder) =>
            {
                configurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                {
                    var azureAppConfigConnectionString = hostingContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
```

[image: debug screen cap]

Comment: Is your app .NET Core 6 WebApp or a Console App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even Iam getting the user secret value null with the code which you have provided.

I am able to retrieve the user secret with few changes.

Thanks @[Christian Nagel](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2020/05/19/azureappconfiguration/#:%7E:text=public%20static%20IHostBuilder%20CreateHostBuilder%20%28string%5B%5D%20args%29%20=%3E%20Host.CreateDefaultBuilder,%28%29;%20var%20connectionString%20=%20settings.GetConnectionString%20%28%22AzureAppConfiguration%22%29;%20config.AddAzureAppConfiguration%20%28connectionString%29;) for the code snippet.

- Add `configurationBuilder.Build();`  and then retrieve the value from the variable.

***My `Program.cs` file***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration;
using System;

public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
   }

   private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configurationBuilder) =>
               {
                   var mysettings = configurationBuilder.Build();
                   var azureAppConfigConnectionString = mysettings.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");

                   configurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                   {
                       options.Connect(azureAppConfigConnectionString);                              
                   });
               })
               .UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! var mysettings = configurationBuilder.Build(); was what I was missing.